# Dynatrace Service URL and RUM

Tags: dynatrace

I have one agent installed for the Dynatrace and configured Dashboard.There are multiple rest end points for my application. I am able to monitor and get the metrics for those end points on the Dashboard using the Service metric tile. I have two questions related to this:

1. Is it possible to monitor the URL ( external to my application) and get the metrics in the same way as I did for rest end points on the Dashboard?

Note: I am able to see the those URL services when I click any of the the rest end point service flow.

2. I enabled RUM and able to see the Java script injection in the URL ( ruxitagentjs getting loaded). In my application, this URL in turn redirects to another URL which will be the welcome page for my application. I am not able to see RUM not loading the JS on this URL. Why is that so?

Answer (score 0):

1. If the URL is external to your application, you can enable synthetic
   monitoring on the URL but you will not still see the RUM unless you
   install Dynatrace agent on the server which serves this external
   URL.
2. When you enabled RUM, the javascript gets injected to the URL to give you the
   end to end view. In your case, the starting point is browser and will show the
   URL but will not show intermediaries which don't have Dynatrace installed.

   In my case, I have an App X which is served by App Server A and B , fronted by Web Server C and D. This Web server is load balanced by an F5 lets say E.

- When you enable RUM with agent only in A and B. You will see E , A/B in service flow
- When you enable RUM with agent in A ,B ,C and D. You will see E , A/B and C/D in service flow